# FunctionIndexingException Can't bind Table to type on Azure WebJob Load

Tags: exception, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I think this is a case of [out of date documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2014/03/06/azure-storage-bindings-part-3-tables.aspx) but I'm unable to find a more recent example.

Using the following code generates an exception on the initialisation of the webjob and it gets stuck in a "pending restart" loop.

```
public static void GenerateExcelFile(
        [QueueTrigger("excel")] JobFile message,
        Guid Id,
        [Table("JobFile")] IDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, object> table,            
    {
        //More Code
    }
```

Replacing "object" with "JobFile" produces the same error. It's quite a length stacktrace so I've only posted the top of it here. Using ILSpy it looks like this shouldn't work so I'm not sure if this feature has been removed since the tutorial was written.

```
[09/13/2014 11:07:53 > be5c40: ERR ] Unhandled Exception:
        Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException:
            Error indexing method 'GenerateExcelFile' ---> 
            System.InvalidOperationException: Can't bind Table to type
           'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String],System.Object]'.
[09/13/2014 11:07:53 > be5c40: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableAttributeBindingProvider.TryCreateAsync(BindingProviderContext context)
[09/13/2014 11:07:53 > be5c40: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.CompositeBindingProvider.<TryCreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I've tried this on 0.5 beta and 0.6 beta of the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation that you are pointing to is out of date. IDictionary binding was removed for Tables. You can use ICollector binding for Inserting or replacing, TableEntity/ IQueryable binding for reading and CloudTable binding for modifying an entity.
The following samples demonstrate Tables usage
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/TableOperations
https://github.com/bradygaster/siteMonitR

Answer (score 0):

As I had to search a while to find how to use the ICollector binding, I thought I'd share. 
It looks like it belongs to a new release in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs so make sure you are using the version 0.6.0-beta.

In your case it would be something like

```
public static void GenerateExcelFile(
    [QueueTrigger("excel")] JobFile message,
    Guid Id,
    [Table("JobFile")] ICollector<JobFile> tableBinding          
{
    //More Code
}

public class JobFile
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

P.S. I have not tested this! :P

See the link for details

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/09/12/announcing-the-0-6-0-beta-preview-of-microsoft-azure-webjobs-sdk.aspx